# Audio in source footage cuts out and starts over a third of the way through (Premiere Pro CS6)

Tags: premiere, mp4

This is a very odd issue that I have been experiencing with a particular video clip.

I have a 2 hour long clip that stops the audio at exactly 00:45:21:03 and starts over, as in the audio from the start of the clip continues right at this mark. The clip plays perfectly in VLC (and every other video player) but is consistently an issue in premiere, even in new sequences and projects.

I've tried importing through File>Import with no difference.
I've tried renaming and moving the file with no difference.

The clip is a movie ripped from a dvd, which hasn't been a problem in the past.